# Search multiple times in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array that contains some of these 3 values: `['daily', 'monthly', 'yearly']`

but sometimes the array only contains: `['monthly', 'daily']`

and what I want is to get the minimum between these 3 values which is `daily` and if not there I want `monthly` and also if it's not there I want the `yearly`. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: `if (array.includes('daily')) { /* DAILY */ } else if (array.includes('monthly')) { /* MONTHLY */ } else { /* YEARLY */ }`

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry but cannot get what you mean. Please show the examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can approach this issue by comparing the values `daily`, `monthly`, and `yearly` alphabetically/by ASCII order

Comment: nicely spotted, I didn't even think about this approach. Could you please add a code example in your answer?

Comment: By using `string1.localeCompare(string2):` **returns -1 if smaller, 1 if bigger, and 0 if equal.** use it while iterating through the array.
If your array could contain only those 3 values, just use : `array.includes('daily')`

Comment: Ok, I was thinking about alphabetical ascending sort of the array, then smaller value will be array[0]

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach that doesn't rely on alphabetic ordering (and would therefore still work when adding new intervals like `hourly`):

```js
function getLowest (arr) {
  const order = ['daily', 'monthly', 'yearly'] 
  return order.find(val => arr.includes(val))
}
```

This works because `find` will return the *first* matching result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one-liner function:

```js
const arr1 = ['daily', 'monthly', 'yearly'], arr2 = ['monthly', 'yearly'], arr3 = ['yearly'], [d,m,y] = arr1;
const lowestVal = (arr) => arr.find(x => x===d) ?? arr.find(x => x===m) ?? y;

console.log(lowestVal(arr1));
console.log(lowestVal(arr2));
console.log(lowestVal(arr3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function you just need to pass your array it will return a minimum value.

```js
function getMinimum(arr)
{
    return arr.includes('daily') ? 'daily' : arr.includes('monthly') ? 'monthly' : arr.includes('yearly') ? 'yearly' : "";
}
var arr1 = ['daily', 'monthly', 'yearly'];
console.log(getMinimum(arr1));
```